# Adding text to a newly added element

Tags: d3.js

This is the whole code you need:

https://raw.github.com/alignedleft/d3-book/master/chapter_09/25_adding_values.html

It is referencing `D3` locally but for faster work you can just refrence it from its website like this instead:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

It will create some chart like this:

[image]

Notice the newly added charts on the ones that don't have a text label on them.

Part of code that is adding labels is towards the very end of the code and is this:

```
            svg.selectAll("text")
               .data(dataset)
               .transition()
               .duration(500)
               .text(function(d) {
                    return d;
               })
               .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                    return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
               })
               .attr("y", function(d) {
                    return h - yScale(d) + 14;
               });
```

As an exercise I am trying to modify the code so I can update the new bars also with their text data, but still couldn't figure it out.   How would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to handle the `.enter()` selection. The code would look like this.

```
svg.selectAll("text")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("text")
           .text(function(d) {
                return d;
           })
           .attr("x", function(d, i) {
                return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
           })
           .attr("y", function(d) {
                return h - yScale(d) + 14;
           });
```

Have a look at [this tutorial](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html) for more information.

Comment: thanks for the point on using enter() ... We are getting close :) but if you try this, all the text is getting out of order now... so may have more work to do with scales or something ...

Comment: This is most likely because of the order in which you're passing the data to `.data()` -- the order actually matters unless you specify a function that tells it how to match elements. All of this is explained in the tutorial I've linked to.